# Why does "as" cause a SyntaxError in an "except" statement in Jython 2.5?

Tags: python, python-2.x, jython

I got the following syntax error at the following line when I run my program in jython:

```
except Exception as detail:
```

SyntaxError: mismatched input 'as' expecting COLON

but on python is it ok? What is wrong? I am trying to use the stanford pos tagger api (java) in my python program. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 2 current versions of Jython: the 2.5 version is the stable one, and 2.7 is a release candidate. The `as` syntax for `except` appeared in CPython 2.6 and thus will be supported in Jython 2.7; I guess you're using Jython 2.5,

You can use the older (Python 3 incompatible)  `except` syntax in Jython 2.5:

```
except Exception, detail:
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, it works! btw if i switch to jython from python, how do i use the custom libraries like nltk i've installed on python to work on jython...

Comment: @goh: Consider opening a separate question for that.