# In Python, what's the difference between 'except Exception as e' and 'except Exception, e'

Tags: python, exception

In python, there are two ways to catch an exception

```
except Exception, e:

except Exception as e:
```

It seems like 'as e' is the one to use going forward.  In what version of python did this change?  Any idea why?

Comment: The `as e` syntax was introduced in Python 2.6.

Comment: Just a note for anyone using Jython, who reads this and decides to replace all "Exception, e" with "Exception as e": it's not supported yet, as of Jython 2.5.2. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020966/jython-syntaxerror

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> This PEP introduces changes intended to help eliminate ambiguities in Python's grammar, simplify exception classes, simplify garbage collection for exceptions and reduce the size of the language in Python 3.0.

[PEP 3110: "Catching Exceptions in Python 3000"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/)

Comment: But I'm using 2.6 and I have a access to both styles.  My coworker had to change by code to `except Exception, e` instead of `except Exception as e` because (stuck) he's using an older version.

Comment: The new grammar was backported to 2.6, but the old grammar was not removed.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer for the why: `Exception, e` and `Exception, TypeError` are hard to tell apart. Long answer: what Ignacio said.

Answer (score 14):

The first proposal for using the "as" is here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-March/062449.html.
They thought it would be more intuitive to read the code

Comment: That was a good find. It's always nice to look at it through a historical perspective!