# jython syntax error mismatched input 'as' expecting colon

Tags: tomcat, jython, devops

when i am trying to convert my project into war file using jython.I have installed python 3.2 and jython 2.5.2 version on my pc

1)Went to the project directory Ran this command on commandline
*jython manage.py buildwar --include-java-libs=/path/to/jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar:/path/to/postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar*

2)getting the following error:

[image]

I dont know whats wrong i am trying to deploy my project on Tomcat to build a pipeline.I  need to convert my project into WAR format.I could not find anything on the internet regarding this problem. Please help me out thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jython syntaxerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020966/jython-syntaxerror)

Comment: you have to use ","(comma) instead of "as".

Comment: thank you for your reply murali. Can you tell me exactly where do i have to use comma cos i am not sure where is this error coming from i tried finding manage.py file which has the error, i was unable to find it. If you could tell me the process step by step would be a great help thanks!!